# How do I Convert a folder filled with .URL files to a .TXT in Mac OSX terminal or otherwise

Tags: macos, url, terminal, converters

URL files in a  folder labeled Resources.

For all intents and purposes suppose it was my reading list URLs or my Favorites URLs.

Generally people sometimes accumulate a bunch of URL files.

The URL files naturally simply open a website.

If I would like to convert all those URLs to a .TXT or word file so that I can easily copy into my website and use it as links is that possible?

on microsoft they gave the following instructions to do while in CMD on windows. The closest thing to that in Mac did not seem to work for me:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183436

Click Start, point to Find, and then click Files Or Folders.
In the Named box, type *.url.
In the Look In box, type \favorites, where  is the path to your Favorites folder. By default, the Favorites folder is located in the C:\Windows folder in Windows 95 and the C:\Winnt\Profiles\ folder in Windows NT.
Click Find Now.
On the Edit menu, click Select All.
On Edit menu, click Copy.
Click Start, point to Programs, and then click Windows Explorer or Windows NT Explorer.
Click drive C.
On the File menu, point to New, and then click Folder.
Type myurls, and then press ENTER.
Double-click the Myurls folder.
On the Edit menu, click Paste.
Click Start, point to Programs, and then click MS-DOS Prompt or Command Prompt.

```
Type the following commands at the command prompt, pressing ENTER after each line:


 1. cd \ 

 2. cd myurls

 3. copy *.url url.txt
```

That is what Microsoft support said and as far as I understand correct me if I'm wrong it would take your favorites and convert them into a plain text file so you can click on each link at your leisure.

I have a similar application here.

**These are the commands I used:**

```
 cd resources
 cp *.url url.txt
```

I got the following message:

```
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are standard Windows `*.url` files, you can do this:

```
grep ^URL * |sed 's/URL=//'   > mylinks.txt
```

then just the website names will be in the file `mylinks.txt`.

Furthermore, you could add `| sort | uniq` if you would like your URL's in alphabetical order with duplicates removed. Like this:

```
grep ^URL *.url | sed 's/URL=//' | sort | uniq > mySortedLinks.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest UNIX equivalent to DOS `copy` when used like this is `cat`:

```
cat *.url > urls.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this worked but the formatting sucks. There probably isn't a way to do something about that?

Comment: Not sure, what is the formatting like and what would you want it to be?